# Chrome on Android Issues with reloading JQM pages - Galaxy tablet

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm having major issues testing my jquery mobile app on Chrome for Android tablets. It works everywhere else except for chrome on android tab.

When I click any button on the page that navigates away from the page, it will refresh the same page I'm in and put it in a popup box. But, if you close the popup and hit any button again it works.

I have a screen shot here...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAWsD.png

Here is my code:

```
<%@page language="abap" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Leave Request Approval</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile- 1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
.ui-field-contain {
border-bottom-width : 0px !important;
}

</style>
</head>

<!-- Details Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="leave_details" data-theme = "b" >
<body>
<div id="Head" data-theme = "b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<a href="" data-role="button" data-theme = "b" class="ui-btn-left">
Back
</a>
<% DATA: lv_head TYPE string.
CONCATENATE 'Leave Request' '-' INTO lv_head SEPARATED BY space.
CONCATENATE lv_head model->ms_details-type_txt INTO lv_head SEPARATED BY space.
CONCATENATE lv_head '-' model->ms_details-emp_name INTO lv_head SEPARATED BY space. %>
<h3>
<%= lv_head. %>
</h3>
</div> <!--End Header -->
<div data-role="content" data-scroll="true">

<% IF model->mv_error IS NOT INITIAL AND model->ms_details IS INITIAL. %>
<span style="color: #FF0000;"> <b> <%= model->mv_error. %> </b> </span>
<% RETURN. %>
<% ELSE. %>

<% IF model->mv_success IS NOT INITIAL OR
model->mv_error IS NOT INITIAL. %>
<div> <!--Begin top portion of page -->

<% IF model->mv_success IS NOT INITIAL. %>
<span style="color: #008000;"> <b> <%= model->mv_success. %> </b> </span>
<% ENDIF. %>

<% IF model->mv_error IS NOT INITIAL. %>
<span style="color: #FF0000;"> <b> <%= model->mv_error. %> </b> </span>
<% CLEAR: model->mv_error. %>
<% IF model->mv_locked = abap_false. %>
<% RETURN. %>
<% ENDIF. %>
<% ENDIF. %>

<%-- <p style="text-align: center;" data-mce-style="text-align: center;">
<b>
<%= model->ms_details-emp_name. %>
</b>
</p>--%>

</div> <!--End top portion of page -->
<% ENDIF. %>

<!--Begin Basic Listbox -->
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme = "b" data-content-theme    = "b">
<h3>
Basic
</h3>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="sup"><b>Supervisor:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="sup" id="sup" value="<%=model->ms_details-sup_name %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="crby"><b>Created By:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="crby" id="crby" value="<%=model->ms_details-cr_by %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="crdt"><b>Created Date:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="crdt" id="crdt" value="<%=model->ms_details-req_date %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="crtm"><b>Created Time:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="crtm" id="crtm" value="<%=model->ms_details-req_time %>" />
</div>

</div> <!--End Basic Listbox -->

<!--Begin Details Listbox -->
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme = "b" data-content-theme = "b">
<h3>
Details
</h3>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="hours"><b>Absence Hours:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="hours" id="hours" value="<%=model->ms_details-hours %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="type"><b>Absence Type:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="type" id="type" value="<%=model->ms_details-awart %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="begdt"><b>Leave Begin Date:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="begdt" id="begdt" value="<%=model->ms_details-date_fr %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="enddt"><b>Leave End Date:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="enddt" id="enddt" value="<%=model->ms_details-date_to %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="begmeal"><b>Begin Meal Time:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="begmeal" id="begmeal" value="<%=model->ms_details-beg_meal %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="endmeal"><b>End Meal Time:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="endmeal" id="endmeal" value="<%=model->ms_details-  end_meal %>" />
</div>

<!--Begin Other Buttons -->
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="" data-theme = "b" data-role="button" data-transition="slide"><font size="2">History</font></a></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><a href="" data-theme = "b" data-role="button" data-transition="slide"><font size="2">Quotas</font></a></div>
</div>
<!--End Other Buttons -->
</div> <!--End Details Listbox -->

<!--Begin Notes Listbox -->
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme = "b" data-content-theme ="b">
<h3>
Notes
</h3>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="medtime"><b>Med Appt Time:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="medtime" id="medtime" value="<%=model->ms_details-med_time %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="fam"><b>Family Rel:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="fam" id="fam" value="<%=model->ms_details-relation %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="flu"><b>Influenza:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="flu" id="flu" value="<%=model->ms_details-flu %>" />
</div>

<% DATA: lv_cert TYPE char3.

IF model->ms_details-medcert = abap_true.
lv_cert = 'Yes'.
ELSE.
lv_cert = 'No'.
ENDIF.
%>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="cert"><b>Medical Cert:</b></label>
<input type="text" readonly name="cert" id="cert" value="<%=lv_cert %>" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="Remarks"><b>Remarks:</b></label>
<textarea readonly name="Remarks" id="Remarks" ><%=model->ms_details-remarks %></textarea>
</div>
</div> <!--End Notes Listbox -->

<% IF model->mv_disp NE 'O' AND model->mv_success IS INITIAL. %>

<!--Begin Footer-->
<div id="Footer" data-theme = "b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h3></h3>

<a href="" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop"     data-theme = "b" class="ui-btn-left">
<% IF model->mv_done_only = abap_false. %>
Approve
<% ELSE. %>
Done
<% ENDIF. %>
</a>

<% IF model->mv_done_only = abap_false. %>
<a href="" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop"     data-theme = "b" class="ui-btn-right">
&nbsp; Reject &nbsp;
</a>
<% ENDIF. %>
</div>
<!--End Footer-->
<% ENDIF. %>
<% ENDIF. %>

</div> <!--End Content -->
</body>
</div> <!--End Details Page -->

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo that I can test.  It should not be showing the popup given that you have a viewport defined.

Comment: Looking at your code, href="" put in href="#"